# ReferenceError: toggle is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, togglebutton

Here is my code and creating two toggle buttons for updating map and panic button but after clicking updating map, nothing is happening and getting this error.

> ReferenceError: toggle is not defined.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport"
  content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
  <title>app template</title>
  <link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript">

    function toggle(el){
      alert('hello');
      if(el.className!="off")
      {
        el.src='images/bt2.png';
        el.className="on";
      }
      else if(el.className=="on")
      {
        el.src='images/bt1.png';
        el.className="off";
      }

      return false;
    }  ​


  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
   <!-- header start -->  
   <div class="top">
     <div class="inner-top-left"><a href="#"><img src="images/arrow.png" alt="" ></a></div>
     <div class="inner-top-right">Setting</div>            
     <div class="clear"></div>
   </div>   

   <!-- header end -->

   <!-- content start -->
   <div class="setting-bg">
     <div class="setting-wrapper">

       <div class="contenair">            
         <div class="setting-left">Updating Map</div>
         <div class="setting-right"><input type="image" src="images/bt2.png" width="41" height="15" class="off" onclick="toggle(this)"/> </div>
         <div class="clear"></div>
       </div>

       <div class="contenair"> 
         <div class="setting-left">Panic Button</div>
         <div class="setting-right"><img src="images/bt2.png" width="41" height="15"></div>
         <div class="clear"></div>
       </div>

     </div>
   </div>
   <!-- content end -->

   <!-- bottom start -->
   <div class="bottom">
     <div class="bottom-btn1"><a href="setting.html"><img src="images/settings39.png"  alt=""></a></div>
     <div class="bottom-btn2"><a href="#" onclick="myFunction()"><img src="images/magnifier5.png" alt=""></a></div>
     <div class="bottom-btn3"><a href="area.html"><img src="images/folder5.png" alt="" ></a></div>
     <div class="bottom-btn4"><a href="GoogleMapDirections.html"><img src="images/map2.png"  alt=""></a></div>
     <div class="clear"></div>
   </div>
   <!-- bottom end -->
 </div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
<!-- Cordova-1.5.0.js file will be here -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cordova-1.5.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script src="helloresponse.js"></script>
</html>
```

There is one another error getting after loading the page:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL         setting.html:27

Comment: I don't see an obvious problem. Are you getting any syntax errors when loading the page?

Comment: Agreed with Barmar, Something else is reason, check syntax near by the toggle function/ if possible post that code too.

Comment: @Barmar , I have edited my answer plz see that...

Comment: @Barmar, End of curly braces after return false inside toggle function...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an illegal invisible character after your toggle function.
When pasted into jsfiddle it's visible: http://jsfiddle.net/7m5Sb/

It's right after the last `}`

Comment: Good catch, I was suspecting something like this.